# How to add a Calendar?

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I would simply like to add a Calendar to my Team Site.
I already have some calendars because I had imported them from a Sharepoint 2010 site. But I cannot find how to add new ones.
Maybe there are some features that I have not activated, but which ones?

I am currently using Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise on premises.

**EDIT:**
The only apps I can add are:

- Document Library
- Custom List
- Tasks

**EDIT2:**
I see the custom master page I made is causing the issue.
Maybe,  do you know  what I could do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Site Contents -> Add an App -> You should see Calendar List in the boxes.. Click to add a new Calendar App/List..

PS: Change of terminology from Lists to App in SharePoint 2013

**UPDATE**

If you don't see Calendar list in Add an App option, please do the following:

Go to Site Settings -> Manage Site Features -> Activate **Team Collaboration Lists** feature

Now if you go to Add an app, you should see Calendar list option

**UPDATE**

You need to add following in your custom MasterPage

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
   <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
   <!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```

Source 
http://blog.drisgill.com/2012/12/design-manager-bug-sharepoint-2013-rtm.html

Comment: Please @Arsalan Adam Khatri, see edit section, with the only apps I can add

Comment: That feature is already activated but I see only those 3 apps. Have you got another idea?

Comment: I have tried that but it seems that the problem is cause by my custom master page. Maybe do you know if I shpould add some code to my custom master page?

Comment: Yes, if I set the default master page it works fine. But I cannot change the master page everytime I need to add an app.

Comment: Please check update

Comment: Thanks a lot @Arsalan Adam Khatri! It was a bug though

Comment: It wasn't called Microsoft, if it wasn't buggy :P

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for this, I created a list template to ease the process:
http://365.webbrewers.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=31

Calendar Creator Free List Template - Add A Simple Calendar To An Office 365 2013 Public Site